# Capybara expect page to have content more than once

Tags: rspec, cucumber, capybara

Does anybody know how to find if a page has a text more than once?

I know I can use

```
expect(page).to have_content("my-text")
```

to check if text appears once. However, I need something like

```
expect(page).to have_content("my-text").twice
```

(which doesn't work).

I'm using capybara v2.1.0.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
expect(page).to have_content("my-text", count: 2)
```

will do what you want in modern versions of Capybara, not sure if that will work in 2.1 but worth trying  (2.1 is over 2 years old now)

**Update:** In Capybara 3.19+ this can also now be written

```
expect(page).to have_content("my-text").twice
```

Comment: For anyone looking for the minitest variant, it's `assert_text "my-text", count: 2`

Answer (score 5):

When you want the text to show at least 2 times (or 2 times and more) you have to use *minimum* instead of *count*.

`expect(page).to have_text(/my-text/, minimum: 2)`

Comment: Yes, and if you want it at least 2 but <= 5 you can do `expect(page).to have_text(/my-text/, minimum: 2, maximum: 5)` or `expect(page).to have_text(/my-text/, between: (2..5))